# Tkinter, PyAutoGUI Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui, tkinter-entry

He everyone! I have one problem and I hope you will help me with that.
I am doing window with question and I want to get the text from Entry.
When I am getting that (I am using 'EntryValue = EntryName.get()') it isn't giving error, but when I want to print it with
PyAutoGUI.typewrite(EntryValue) it isn't print that because there isn't any value
in my variable.

That is my code:

```
**from tkinter import *
import pyautogui as pg
import time
EntryThatAnswersToQuestionValue = ""
def FunctionThatCreatesWindowThatFindsProgramm():
    WindowThatFindsProgram = Toplevel(Root)
    WindowThatFindsProgram.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Murad\Desktop\My Factory\Programmes\J.A.R.V.I.S\Icon\QuestionIcon.ico')
    WindowThatFindsProgram.title("J.A.R.V.I.S. Has a question.")
    WindowThatFindsProgram.geometry('350x250')
    LabelThatExplainsWhatToDoInWindowThatFindsProgram = Label(WindowThatFindsProgram,text="Please, write your programm's name sir."
    ,fg='black',font='Arial 10 bold')
    LabelThatExplainsWhatToDoInWindowThatFindsProgram.pack()
    EntryThatAnswersToQuestion = Entry(WindowThatFindsProgram)
    EntryThatAnswersToQuestion.pack()
    EntryThatAnswersToQuestionValue = EntryThatAnswersToQuestion.get()
    OKButton = Button(WindowThatFindsProgram,text="     OK     ",fg='black',font='Arial 10 bold',command=FunctionThatFindsProgramm)
    OKButton.pack()
def FunctionThatFindsProgramm():
    pg.hotkey('winleft')
    time.sleep(1)
    pg.typewrite(EntryThatAnswersToQuestionValue,3)
    time.sleep(1)
    pg.hotkey('enter')**

Root = Tk()
Root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Murad\Desktop\My Factory\Programmes\J.A.R.V.I.S\Icon\Icon.ico')
Root.title("J.A.R.V.I.S.")
Root.geometry('960x540')
Root['bg'] = 'black'

MainMenu = Frame(Root,bg='black')
MainMenu.pack()

JarvisTextGreeting = Label(MainMenu,text="Hello, sir. You can tell the below commands for execution.",bg='black'
,fg='blue',font='Arial 15 bold')
JarvisTextGreeting.pack()

ButtonFindingTheProgramm = Button(MainMenu,text="J.A.R.V.I.S. Please find programm that I will tell you on my PC"
,bg='blue',fg='black',font='Arial 10 bold',command=FunctionThatCreatesWindowThatFindsProgramm)
ButtonFindingTheProgramm.pack()

Root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You called `.get()` on your Entry *immediately* after creating it.  Of course the variable is empty - when has the user had any chance to type anything in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take the variable as global variable in the function:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui as pg
import time
EntryThatAnswersToQuestionValue = ""
def FunctionThatCreatesWindowThatFindsProgramm():
    global EntryThatAnswersToQuestionValue
    WindowThatFindsProgram = Toplevel(Root)
    WindowThatFindsProgram.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Murad\Desktop\My Factory\Programmes\J.A.R.V.I.S\Icon\QuestionIcon.ico')
    WindowThatFindsProgram.title("J.A.R.V.I.S. Has a question.")
    WindowThatFindsProgram.geometry('350x250')
    LabelThatExplainsWhatToDoInWindowThatFindsProgram = Label(WindowThatFindsProgram,text="Please, write your programm's name sir."
    ,fg='black',font='Arial 10 bold')
    LabelThatExplainsWhatToDoInWindowThatFindsProgram.pack()
    EntryThatAnswersToQuestion = Entry(WindowThatFindsProgram)
    EntryThatAnswersToQuestion.pack()
    EntryThatAnswersToQuestionValue = EntryThatAnswersToQuestion.get()
    OKButton = Button(WindowThatFindsProgram,text="     OK     ",fg='black',font='Arial 10 bold',command=FunctionThatFindsProgramm)
    OKButton.pack()
def FunctionThatFindsProgramm():
    pg.hotkey('winleft')
    time.sleep(1)
    pg.typewrite(EntryThatAnswersToQuestionValue,3)
    time.sleep(1)
    pg.hotkey('enter')

Root = Tk()
Root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Murad\Desktop\My Factory\Programmes\J.A.R.V.I.S\Icon\Icon.ico')
Root.title("J.A.R.V.I.S.")
Root.geometry('960x540')
Root['bg'] = 'black'

MainMenu = Frame(Root,bg='black')
MainMenu.pack()

JarvisTextGreeting = Label(MainMenu,text="Hello, sir. You can tell the below commands for execution.",bg='black'
,fg='blue',font='Arial 15 bold')
JarvisTextGreeting.pack()

ButtonFindingTheProgramm = Button(MainMenu,text="J.A.R.V.I.S. Please find programm that I will tell you on my PC"
,bg='blue',fg='black',font='Arial 10 bold',command=FunctionThatCreatesWindowThatFindsProgramm)
ButtonFindingTheProgramm.pack()

Root.mainloop()
```